# How can I increase the mouse pointer speed beyond the limits set by the Mouse preferences dialog?

Tags: configuration, mouse

In the `Mouse preferences` dialog I've set the `acceleration` to max and the `sensitivity` to min and the mouse pointer is not exactly sluggish, but I'd like to make it even faster. Is it possible to be done by setting some value in the `procfs` or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `xset` command allows you to change quite a few aspects of your desktop, including mouse acceleration.

```
xset m 2 1
```

The first number is the acceleration, the second is threshold. So, in the example I provided, the mouse will go 2X as fast once it's traveled 1px across the screen. Zero has some special connotations, so I'd stick with 1.

I wouldn't think you would need to set the acceleration too high to get what you're looking for.

This effect will disappear once you reboot/restart. If it works for you, the command can be added to your "Startup Applications" to be applied automatically.

Good luck!

Comment: Set it to `16 1` and is working *splendidly* now! Thanks!

Comment: Wow, you weren't kidding when you said you wanted it fast! :)

Comment: I needed to slow my mouse down, so I used `xset m 6/5 0`. @AlbusDumbledore you're a cyborg. I could hardly click on my terminal window with that setting!

Comment: Haha. Well, it depends on the mouse. With nice mice I'd go lower, like 12-13.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how to make this change permanent?

Comment: @guettli The following question might help: https://askubuntu.com/q/814/6016

Comment: You're a wizard Albus

Comment: It doesn't work on ubuntu 18.10

Comment: @DrunkenPoney This is an old answer; it's possible Ubuntu has changed enough under-the-hood to prevent it from working. If you find a better solution, please share it as a new answer!

Comment: Also reporting this does not work recently (I'm on Arch). I think it's due to changes in X have not yet figured out how to fix.

Comment: what about those on wayland ?

Comment: @尤金寶 漢子 xset is an X windows utility, so you'd have to find an equivalent for Wayland. I've never used Wayland, but I'll post a new answer if I encounter it.

Answer (score 4):

There is a number after which the speed isn't increasing.

After this number I've set it to 30, and 200 and the speed is the same. It's still slow, but it is faster than it was before.

I guess it depends on the mouses DPI.
The Steelseries Sensei has the most DPI: 16000 DPI.
A higher DPI is always better once you know it, but it isn't really that fast when you have one or more 4k monitors.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing on Ubuntu 23, and found a solution, using `solaar`
The only way I was able to install it and correctly detect my mouse was using a system-wide pip installation with:

```
sudo apt update
pip3 install evdev python-xlib
sudo pip3 install solaar
```

After that, I needed to start it with `sudo solaar` because otherwise my mouse was not detected. Finally, I just increased the Sensitivity settings in the GUI and had a much faster mouse speed than with the system settings limit.
Probably not the best way to do it, but it worked for me.