# Can't slow down the pointer speed enough

Tags: 12.04, mouse

I have changed my mouse, bought a new set but still no use - it's too fast for a designer.

And in the new version (12.04) I don't even know how to find the `xorg.conf`, or anything would help

Is not there any application for this to adjust mouse sensivity more than the default options like Logitech applications for Windows?

Keyboard and mouse model: Logitech mk520 wireless laser mouse & keyboard set.
Mouse model: m310 (laser, wireless)

Answer (score 23):

- open dash by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> /  (button with windows logo)
- Search for "mouse". Open `Mouse preferences`
- Reduce the speed and see if it works.

If above method doesn't work, try with the `xset` command. It allows you to change quite a few aspects of your desktop, including mouse acceleration.

> xset m 1 1

The first number is the acceleration, the second is threshold.
Don't give any value as zero.

Linked Question:
[How can I increase the mouse pointer speed beyond the limits set by the Mouse preferences dialog?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27862/how-can-i-increase-the-mouse-pointer-speed-beyond-the-limits-set-by-the-mouse-pr)

Comment: nope; didn't work. still too fast for me. but thanks for the response. btw, i even tried "0.1" instead of "1"; nope, it didn't work either. :(

Comment: I just look in internet. You can use decimal values. Please try with `0.5` or `0.1 `.

Comment: @Web-E, your solution worked like a champ for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this script could help:

https://github.com/rubo77/mouse-speed

you only have to configure the identifier of your mouse in the head of the script using
    `xinput --list --short`

the script sets
    `xinput --set-prop`

Comment: I updated mouse-speed to version 1.1

Comment: Good work, @rubo77

Answer (score 0):

They say `xset` supports values below 1 but I found any value below I entered (tried fractions and decimals) was the same as 1.

https://patrickmn.com/aside/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/ worked for me. You can achieve very slow mouse settings.