# how to increase mouse movement speed in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mouse

the maximum available speed for mouse is not very comfortable. i want to increase it.. how to do that?? is there an app to customize these sort of stuffs (preferable since I am new to ubuntu).
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using a touchpad or a mouse?

Comment: This solved it for me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177640

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Run in terminal `xinput --list --short` and find your mouse id (for me `id=12`)
2. Run in terminal `xinput --list-props 12` (change `12` for the right id)
3. Find the id for the property `Device Accel Constant Deceleration` (for me 262)
4. Run in terminal `xinput --set-prop 12 262 0.1` (change `12` and `262` for the correct id)

The last number (`0.1`) is the important value. The smaller the number the faster your cursor moves (default value is 1.0). Play around with the values till you find one that works for you and then add the command to the startup applications GUI.

Good luck

---

Comment: i get a weird message when i type in the last command. btw i entered th id of the touchpad since i am using touchpad.  it's too long to paste the response here

Comment: @KarthikeyanSaravanabavan what is the essence of the message. Can you give me a link to the message (ex. Pastebin, Dropbox, Github)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx0H8TnBYDUhRThvU2dfcFhoX0U/view?usp=sharing

this link will help i guess

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx0H8TnBYDUhRThvU2dfcFhoX0U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @KarthikeyanSaravanabava Sorry, my mistake. You have a syntax error, it should be `xinput --set-prop` not `xinput --set-props`. I have edited my answer

Comment: it works. thanks. and how to add this command to the startup applications? can you help me in that also?

Comment: @KarthikeyanSaravanabavan There is an application called `Startup Applications`. You can open it by searching in the dash (top left button). Once you open startup applications, simply press `Add`. In the command field add your command. Also give it a name in the name field. Press `Add` then `close`. Done!. You can also take a look at the beginning of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) answer. There are a bunch of tutorials all over the Internet. Try figuring it out on your own next time before asking for help on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The first place to speed up your mouse is in Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad -> Pointer Speed.

If that maximum is not enough try this answer : 
[How can I increase the mouse pointer speed beyond the limits set by the Mouse preferences dialog?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27862/how-can-i-increase-the-mouse-pointer-speed-beyond-the-limits-set-by-the-mouse-pr)

Basically, add the following command to `Startup Application` and change the second number (2 in this case) to the desired mouse speed (2X faster, 3X faster...).

`xset m 2 1`

Good luck

Comment: I tried doing this.. i even tried the xset m 5000 1.. it doesn't make any difference in my mouse speed

Comment: @KarthikeyanSaravanabavan please see second answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try using piper. It is available trough the Ubuntu repositories, so just install it via

`sudo apt install piper`

It has a GUI and it worked very well for my Logitech G402 on Ubuntu 20.04 to increase the mouse speed pretty much. You can change some settings for the buttons and even the LED are controllable.

Comment: Upvoting this as every other answer wasn't able to increase my mouse speed, but changing the DPI with piper instantly worked (plus the other features are neat).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix it after an update from 16.04 to 18.04 (mouse became too slow after the update).

Like in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/876273/391744

but change instead just the acceleration profile from `0` to `2`:

1. Run in terminal `xinput --list --short` and find your mouse id (for me `id=12`)
2. Run in terminal `xinput --list-props 12` (change `12` for the right id)
3. Find the id for the property `Device Accel Profile` (for me `267`)
4. Run in terminal `xinput --set-prop 12 267 2` (change `12` and `267` for the correct id)

Comment: The acceleration doesn't go above 1.0 on my system. To speed up my high dpi mouse I had to alter the transformation matrix as described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177640

Answer (score 0):

For a GUI tool try typing this into your Terminal:

```
dconf-editor
```

For (Ubuntu-Mate-18.04.02) I use the Default of (`-1`) for both. My settings are here:-

```
/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/mouse/motion-acceleration

/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/mouse/motion-threshold
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. I found a solution [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdTyv45styU):

1. Find your device id using `xinput --list --short`
2. Find `Coordinate Transformation Matrix` property id using `xinput --list-props {device-id}`
3. Increase the speed (2x in this case) using: `xinput --set-prop {device-id} {property-id} 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1` (replace 2 with 1.5 if it's too fast).