# How to move mouse faster?

Tags: mouse, 18.04, mouse-pointer

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 to the Dell xps 13(9370) with a mouse Logicool M590.

The mouse can be connected successfully, but pointer speed is not fast enough for me.

I tried Mouse & Touchpad section of system config application and `xinput --set-float-prop pointer:M585/M590 "libinput Accel Speed" 1` command, but I got same result from both setting.

Are there any other way to change mouse speed?

Thanks,

This [page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875817/how-to-increase-mouse-movement-speed-in-ubuntu-16-04) expalins how to use xinput command, but I need other method to make mouse pointer moves faster.

`xset` command mentioned in the page doesn't work. I guess `xset` command doesn't work with libinput.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/875817/how-to-increase-mouse-movement-speed-in-ubuntu-16-04?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to increase mouse movement speed in ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875817/how-to-increase-mouse-movement-speed-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: @singrium to get the possible duplicate to the attention of close voters, use the `flag` link under the post with the reason `a duplicate...`. It'll add the comment for you as well.

Comment: @singrium, @ salmanarshad1999   Thank you for comments. But as I wrote, I already tried xinput command. I need other method to make mouse pointer faster.

Comment: xset command mentioned in the [page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875817/how-to-increase-mouse-movement-speed-in-ubuntu-16-04) doesn't work.
I guess xset command doesn't work with libinput.

Answer (score 1):

For me it made the sensitivity and acceleration just like it was in 16.04 (16.04 to 18.04 update slowed the mouse way too much).

put

```
xinput --set-prop 'ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse' 'Device Accel Profile' 2
```

into

```
~/.xsessionrc
```

To get the name of the mouse:

```
xinput --list --short
```

Derived from in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/876273/391744

but changed instead just the acceleration profile from `0` to `2`:

1. Run in terminal `xinput --list --short` and find your mouse id (for me `id=12`)
2. Run in terminal `xinput --list-props 12` (change `12` for the right id)
3. Find the id for the property `Device Accel Profile` (for me `267`)
4. Run in terminal `xinput --set-prop 12 267 2` (change `12` and `267` for the correct id)

Comment: Thank you. But it looks my device doesn't have `Device Accel Profile`

`
    $ xinput --set-prop 20 'Device Accel Profile' 2
    property 'Device Accel Profile' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
`

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
xinput --list --short
```

There are two type of input devices: pointers and keyboards.

For some reason, the M585/M590 is located in both types and these are [different devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXZMi.png).

You need to change the pointer device settings, to list all the settings for the pointer use this command.

```
xinput --list-props "M585/M590 Mouse"
```

You will find there this setting "libinput Accel Speed".

Change it like that:

```
xinput --set-prop "M585/M590 Mouse" "libinput Accel Speed" 0.8
```

You can check wheather the options were changed correctly by doing `xinput --list-props "M585/M590 Mouse"` again.