# Changing Mouse Speed - No "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" Property

Tags: mouse, mouse-pointer

I am attempting to change the mouse speed for a Logitech M335 mouse on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and cannot find the "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" property described in Step 3 of [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875817/how-to-increase-mouse-movement-speed-in-ubuntu-16-04). Has there been a change to this property name? I only have these properties with Accel listed:

- libinput Accel Speed
- libinput Accel Speed Default
- libinput Accel Profiles Available
- libinput Accel Profile Enabled
- libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default

Should I be changing one of these properties or is there another method?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue on Ubuntu 20.04.

I was able increase the mouse speed using the following process

```
user@ubuntu-20.04:~$ xinput --list | grep pointer | grep Ducky
⎜   ↳ Ducky Ducky One2 Mini RGB                 id=29   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

where "Ducky" is the brand name of the device whose input speed needed to be changed. Note that the id of the device is **29**.

```
user@ubuntu-20.04:~$ xinput --list-props 29 | grep "Coordinate Transformation Matrix"
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (188): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

We learn from above that the prop ID of the Coordinate Transformation matrix is **188**

```
user@ubuntu-20.04:~$ xinput --set-prop 29 188 a b c d e f g h i
```

Where each variable above constructs a matrix as shown below

```
[[a b c]
 [d e f]
 [g h i]]
```

To increase my pointer speed to double its current speed, I used the following matrix

```
[[2 0 0]
 [0 2 0]
 [0 0 1]]
```

This does speed up the pointer but comes with the drawback that the pointer is "skipping" pixels. It can also cause issues with cursor jumping with applications that take control of the cursor.

To alleviate these issues you will have to look at using an Affine Transformation Matrix (See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954781/calculating-the-translation-of-an-affine-matrix-so-that-it-centres-during-scalin)